# Как понять что канал закончил передавать данные

Tags: golang

Функция ExecutePipeline принимает слайс job, при этом выходной канал предыдущей job передается в последующую в качестве входного:

```
type job func(in, out chan interface{})

freeFlowJobs := []job{
    job(func(in, out chan interface{}) {
        out <- uint32(1)
        out <- uint32(3)
        out <- uint32(4)
    }),
    job(func(in, out chan interface{}) {
        for val := range in {
            out <- val.(uint32) * 3
        }
    }),
}


ExecutePipeline(freeFlowJobs...)
```

Первая job имеет приблизительно такой вид - в канал эмитится ограниченное число данных, канал после этого не закрывается.

Как мне в ExecutePipeline или во второй job понять, что в канал данные болше приходить не будут?

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно использовать буферизированный канал.
2. Определить длину очереди в канале.
3. Итерировать канал в цикле.

   lenIn := len(in)

   for index := 0; index < lenIn; index++ {

   ```
   vars := <-in
   ```

   }

Comment: хорошая идея, надо попробовать